# What does model.train() do in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Does it call `forward()` in `nn.Module`? I thought when we call the model, `forward` method is being used.
Why do we need to specify train()?

Comment: These days there is exist a documentation inside PyTorch: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html you can check documentation, it describes pretty clear I think. Another libraries/frameworks can have lack of documentation, but in PyTorch I think official documentation is pretty nice.

Comment: Perhaps "configure_training" or "set_training_mode" would have been better names for this function.

Comment: it simple changes the `self.training` via `self.training = training` recursively for all modules by doing `self.train(False)`. In fact that is what `self.train` does, changes the flag to true recursively for all modules. see code: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6e1a5b1196aa0277a2113a4bca75b6e0f2b4c0c8/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1432

Answer (score 302, accepted):

`model.train()` tells your model that you are training the model. This helps inform layers such as Dropout and BatchNorm, which are designed to behave differently during training and evaluation. For instance, in training mode, BatchNorm updates a moving average on each new batch; whereas, for evaluation mode, these updates are frozen.

More details:
`model.train()` sets the mode to train
(see [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.train)). You can call either `model.eval()` or `model.train(mode=False)` to tell that you are testing.
It is somewhat intuitive to expect `train` function to train model but it does not do that. It just sets the mode.

Comment: is there a flag to detect if the model is in eval mode? e.g. `mdl.is_eval()`?

Comment: Use `model.training` flag. It is `False`, when in `eval` mode.

Comment: In the current documentation, I find this "model.train()" is no longer being used: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html

I did a small test with a small 3 layer neural network model with batch norm and dropout and trained it on tabular dataset. I found adding model.train() actually prevented my model accuracy going above 70%. When I removed the line, the accuracy was 87%!

Comment: @Indrajit Did you check that was not in train model, i.e., `model.training` is `False`? I think by default it is true and that is why they omit `model.train()` call. As for your result, I cannot say much without knowing what the data was and if you measure test or train accuracy etc.

Comment: @UmangGupta - It is true that by default model.training is True, but if you look at the link, their training loop, after the train step they have an eval step - where they call model.eval(). This will make model.training as False which they don't reset. I understand this is pretty counter intuitive - and I am puzzled too. Still trying to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @UmangGupta- actually I figured out just now what was happening. My model.train() was actually impacting batchnorm and dropout layers - which in turn was impacting the model performance.

Comment: I wonder how `model.eval()` affects backward pass?

Comment: It won't affect the backward pass directly. It will just use batch norm and dropout in "test" mode which can affect the backward pass. For example, Dropout would become an identity operation and thus have no effect.

Comment: Really bad naming.

Answer (score 97):

Here is the code for [`nn.Module.train()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.train):

```
def train(self, mode=True):
        r"""Sets the module in training mode."""      
        self.training = mode
        for module in self.children():
            module.train(mode)
        return self
```

Here is the code for [`nn.Module.eval()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.eval):

```
def eval(self):
        r"""Sets the module in evaluation mode."""
        return self.train(False)
```

By default, the `self.training` flag is set to `True`, i.e., modules are in train mode by default. When `self.training` is `False`, the module is in the opposite state, eval mode.

Of the most commonly used layers, only [`Dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/dropout.html) and [`BatchNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.html) care about that flag.

Comment: Are there any other layers that support `self.training` flag now ?

Comment: I wonder how `model.eval()` affects backward pass?

Comment: `model.eval()` is is just a switch not to take dropout and batch norms. I have a nice [intro to PyTorch training](https://programming-review.com/pytorch/train) where you can check the forward and backward pass, and [deep intro to PyTorch AD](https://programming-review.com/pytorch/ad) where you can confidently understand the details of PyTorch AD.

Comment: @Melike https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534762/which-pytorch-modules-are-affected-by-model-eval-and-model-train

Answer (score 41):

| `model.train()` | [`model.eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843176/9067615) |
| --- | --- |
| Sets model in **train**ing mode i.e. • `BatchNorm` layers use per-batch statistics • `Dropout` layers activated [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534762/which-pytorch-modules-are-affected-by-model-eval-and-model-train) | Sets model in **eval**uation (inference) mode i.e. • `BatchNorm` layers use running statistics • `Dropout` layers de-activated etc |
|  | Equivalent to `model.train(False)`. |

**Note:** neither of these function calls run forward / backward passes. They tell the model *how* to act *when* run.

This is important as [some modules (layers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534762/which-pytorch-modules-are-affected-by-model-eval-and-model-train) (e.g. `Dropout`, `BatchNorm`) are designed to behave differently during training vs inference, and hence the model will produce unexpected results if run in the wrong mode.

Answer (score 17):

There are two ways of letting the model know your intention i.e do you want to train the model or do you want to use the model to evaluate.
In case of `model.train()` the model knows it has to learn the layers and when we use `model.eval()` it indicates the model that nothing new is to be learnt and the model is used for testing.
`model.eval()` is also necessary because in pytorch if we are using batchnorm and during test if we want to just pass a single image, pytorch throws an error if `model.eval()` is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following model

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

class GraphNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_node_features, num_classes):
        super(GraphNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 16)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(16, num_classes)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training) #Look here
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

Here, the functioning of `dropout` differ in different modes of operation. As you can see, it works only when `self.training==True`. So, when you type `model.train()`, the model's forward function will perform dropout otherwise it will not (say when `model.eval()` or `model.train(mode=False)`).

Answer (score 2):

The current [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.train) states the following:

> This has any [sic] effect only on certain modules. See documentations of particular modules for details of their behaviors in training/evaluation mode, if they are affected, e.g. Dropout, BatchNorm, etc.