# Why there's no .train() method in this Pytorch official tutorial?

Tags: pytorch

So, I just learned Pytorch and they say that you must put the NN in train mode by .train() method, then while inferencing .eval() mode. I'm reading this tutorial and there's no .train() at all. Why is that?

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does model.train() do in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch)

Comment: Please, do not post the same question **at the same time** on SO and [Discuss PyTorch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/where-theres-no-train-method-in-this-pytorch-official-tutorial/49892). At least, wait for _one day_ for an answer in one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.train()` sets the `self.training` property of the module to `True`. `.eval()` sets it to `False`.

As can be seen in the [source for `nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module), this property is initially set to `True`. So, unless you have called `eval()` before you start training, you do not *necessarily* (as per the current implementation) need to call `train()`. **But** the important point is that the module should be in the `self.training=True` state at the time of training, so it is probably a good practice to do so anyway.

Also, currently, only some modules (such as dropout and batchnorm) change their behavior based on the `self.training` property. So you don't *necessarily* have to call `.train()` and `.eval()` if you are not using those specific modules, but again, it is probably good practice to do so anyway for future-proofing your code.