# How to freeze a sub-model for one model, without affecting another sub-model with same pretrianed weightes?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a model composed of model_1, model_2, model_3. and the flow is model_1 and model_2 >>> model_3, how can I set that model _1 do not update and model_2 update. Note that the model_1 and model_2 with same structure and pretrained weights in the beginning of the training process.
When I load one pretrained weight for model_1 and model_2, and frezze model_1 in the **init**, and I find that both models (model_1 and model_2 ) do not update in the trianing.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `train()` and `eval()` methods of your model such that they will only alter your desired sub-model.

An example and some more info regarding `train()`:
[What does model.train() do in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch)