# What do BatchNorm2d's running_mean / running_var mean in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, mean, variance, batch-normalization

I'd like to know what exactly the `running_mean` and `running_var` that I can call from `nn.BatchNorm2d`.

Example code is here where bn means `nn.BatchNorm2d`.

```
vector = torch.cat([
    torch.mean(self.conv3.bn.running_mean).view(1), torch.std(self.conv3.bn.running_mean).view(1),
    torch.mean(self.conv3.bn.running_var).view(1), torch.std(self.conv3.bn.running_var).view(1),
    torch.mean(self.conv5.bn.running_mean).view(1), torch.std(self.conv5.bn.running_mean).view(1),
    torch.mean(self.conv5.bn.running_var).view(1), torch.std(self.conv5.bn.running_var).view(1)
])
```

I couldn't figure out what `running_mean` and `running_var` mean in the Pytorch official documentation and user community.

What do `nn.BatchNorm2.running_mean` and `nn.BatchNorm2.running_var` mean?

Comment: PyTorch implements the [BatchNorm paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), I suggest you to read it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the original Batchnorm paper:

***Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift***,
*Seguey Ioffe* and *Christian Szegedy*, **ICML'2015**

You can see on *Algorithm 1.* how to measure the statistics of a given batch.

[image]

However what is kept in memory across batches is the running stats, *i.e.* the statistics which are measured iteratively at each batch inference. The computation of the running mean and running variance is actually quite well explained in the documentation page of [`nn.BatchNorm2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html):

[image]

By default, the `momentum` coefficient is set to `0.1`, it regulates how much of the current batch statistics will affect the running statistics:

- closer to `1` means the new running stat is closer to the current batch statistics, whereas
- closer to `0` means the current batch stats will not contribute much to updating the new running stats.

It's worth pointing out that `Batchnorm2d` is applied across spatial dimensions, * in addition*, to the batch dimension of course. Given a batch of shape `(b, c, h, w)`, it will compute the statistics across `(b, h, w)`. This means the running statistics are shaped `(c,)`, *i.e.* there are as many statistics components as there are in input channels (for both mean and variance).

Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(10)
>>> x = torch.rand(2,10,2,2)
```

Since `track_running_stats` is set to `True` [by default](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py#L127) on `BatchNorm2d`, it will track the running stats when inferring on [training mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch).

The running mean and variance are initialized to zeros and ones, respectively.

```
>>> running_mean, running_var = torch.zeros(x.size(1)),torch.ones(x.size(1))
```

Let's perform inference on `bn` in training mode and check its running stats:

```
>>> bn(x)
>>> bn.running_mean, bn.running_var
(tensor([0.0650, 0.0432, 0.0373, 0.0534, 0.0476, 
         0.0622, 0.0651, 0.0660, 0.0406, 0.0446]),
 tensor([0.9027, 0.9170, 0.9162, 0.9082, 0.9087, 
         0.9026, 0.9136, 0.9043, 0.9126, 0.9122]))
```

Now let's compute those stats by hand:

```
>>> (1-momentum)*running_mean + momentum*xmean
tensor([[0.0650, 0.0432, 0.0373, 0.0534, 0.0476, 
         0.0622, 0.0651, 0.0660, 0.0406, 0.0446]])

>>> (1-momentum)*running_var + momentum*xvar
tensor([[0.9027, 0.9170, 0.9162, 0.9082, 0.9087, 
         0.9026, 0.9136, 0.9043, 0.9126, 0.9122]])
```