# [pytorch]: Is it necessary to use model.train() and model.eval() in the training, when dropout is not used?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a feed forward neural network and I want to train it with minibatches. The training code is as follows:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for x_batch, y_batch in training_data:
        model.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(x_batch)
        loss = loss_fn(output, y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            output_test = model(x_test)
            loss_t = loss_fn(output_test, y_test)
```

I am wondering if it is necessary to use `model.train()` and `model.eval()` while the model does not have any dropout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does model.train() do in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch)